# Google Analytics - Download hostname table

Tags: google-analytics

I want to download google analytics hostname table data.

[image]

IS this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of the page is a Button called "export" there you can download the table in various formats.

Comment: But it limits the table to 5000 lines. I have twice that amount.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The web interface have a limit of 5000 lines. Solutions for this are discussed on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905867/google-analytics-data-export-limit)

For more than 5000 lines you can use the analytics api. You can try this with the [Google Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/).

If you need more than 10000 lines than you can try also the [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-On](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on)

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot.